# How to define Clojure spec for `'(foo (:x 1 :y 2))`

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

The:

```
(s/def ::a (s/cat :k keyword? :i int?))
(s/def ::b (s/cat :symbol any?
                  :a      (s/coll-of ::a)))
```

specs:
                 `(s/conform ::b '(foo ((:x 1) (:y 2))))`

The:

```
(s/def ::a (s/cat :k keyword? :i int?))
(s/def ::b (s/cat :symbol any?
                  :a      (s/* ::a)))
```

specs:
                 `(s/conform ::b '(foo :x 1 :y 2))`

but how do I spec `(s/conform ::b '(foo (:x 1 :y 2)))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To nest that into a list, you need to wrap it in `s/spec`.  E.g.:

```
(s/def ::b (s/cat :symbol any? :a (s/spec (s/* ::a))))
```

This is mentioned in the [Spec Guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_sequences):

> When regex ops are combined, they describe a single sequence. If you need to spec a nested sequential collection, you must use an explicit call to spec to start a new nested regex context. For example to describe a sequence like [:names ["a" "b"] :nums [1 2 3]], you need nested regular expressions to describe the inner sequential data:
>
> ```
>  (s/def ::nested
>    (s/cat :names-kw #{:names}
>           :names (s/spec (s/* string?))
>           :nums-kw #{:nums}
>           :nums (s/spec (s/* number?))))
>  (s/conform ::nested [:names ["a" "b"] :nums [1 2 3]])
>  ;;=> {:names-kw :names, :names ["a" "b"], :nums-kw :nums, :nums [1 2 3]}
> ```